# CoreAudio does not fill buffer running on device (but in simulator)

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, core-audio, circular-buffer

I am building a CoreAudio application, where i need to process raw input samples from the microphone. I use two threads, where one thread is producing samples from the microphone input and the other thread is consuming samples. These threads share a (well working) circular buffer, whose implementation i have [taken from Github](https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPCircularBuffer) (a good example can be found on [the author's blog](http://atastypixel.com/blog/a-simple-fast-circular-buffer-implementation-for-audio-processing/)).

As a minimal example for my problem, i have put together [a small XCode project on Github](https://github.com/padde/BufferedSamples), so you can see the full code. The App puts the microphone samples into a circular buffer and then reads the buffer from another thread. The consuming thread computes the [average rectified value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average_rectified_value) (ARV) of 500 samples and outputs the ARV on the console.

When i run the app in the iOS Simulator (5.1) everything works fine and i get the desired output:

```
2012-08-21 20:58:31.882 BufferedSamples[23505:6003] 88
2012-08-21 20:58:31.890 BufferedSamples[23505:6003] 108
2012-08-21 20:58:31.890 BufferedSamples[23505:6003] 137
2012-08-21 20:58:31.891 BufferedSamples[23505:6003] 137
2012-08-21 20:58:31.892 BufferedSamples[23505:6003] 106
2012-08-21 20:58:31.901 BufferedSamples[23505:6003] 140
...
```

When i try to run the app on a device (i tried iPhone 3/3GS/4) instead, i get an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error at runtime due to a `NULL` pointer. Therefore i added a check for a `NULL` pointer in the CoreAudio callback function (in the file `DummyRecorder.m`):

```
// render samples into buffer
AudioBufferList bufferList;
bufferList.mNumberBuffers = 1;
bufferList.mBuffers[0].mNumberChannels = 1;
bufferList.mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize = inNumberFrames * kTwoBytesPerSInt16;
bufferList.mBuffers[0].mData = NULL;
AudioUnitRender(dummyRecorder->audioUnit, ioActionFlags, inTimeStamp, kInputBus, inNumberFrames, &bufferList);

// move samples to ring buffer
if (bufferList.mBuffers[0].mData != NULL)
    TPCircularBufferProduceBytes(&dummyRecorder->buffer, bufferList.mBuffers[0].mData, bufferList.mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize);
else
    NSLog(@"null pointer");
```

When i run the app in the simulator, i still get the desired output, but on the device, i get the following:

```
2012-08-21 21:15:38.903 BufferedSamples[544:3b03] null pointer
2012-08-21 21:15:38.926 BufferedSamples[544:3b03] null pointer
2012-08-21 21:15:38.949 BufferedSamples[544:3b03] null pointer
2012-08-21 21:15:38.972 BufferedSamples[544:3b03] null pointer
2012-08-21 21:15:38.996 BufferedSamples[544:3b03] null pointer
2012-08-21 21:15:39.019 BufferedSamples[544:3b03] null pointer
...
```

How is it possible that CoreAudio allocates and fills a buffer correctly in the simulator, but on the device leaves the buffer untouched? What have i missed?

[The complete code of my example can be found on Github.](https://github.com/padde/BufferedSamples)

### Edit

I added a [method to check for errors](http://pastebin.com/zMc3xBMS) after CoreAudio calls, as `@MichaelTyson` suggested. Now i am doing this in my callback:

```
OSStatus err = AudioUnitRender(dummyRecorder->audioUnit, ioActionFlags, inTimeStamp, kInputBus, inNumberFrames, &bufferList);

// move samples to ring buffer
if (checkResult(err, "AudioUnitRender"))
    TPCircularBufferProduceBytes(&dummyRecorder->buffer, bufferList.mBuffers[0].mData, bufferList.mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize);
```

I have also updated the code on Github. Running the app in the simulator produces no errors, whereas running it on a device gives me the following errors:

```
2012-08-22 11:19:49.248 BufferedSamples[637:3b03] /DummyRecorder.m:50: AudioUnitRender result -50 FFFFFFCE Œˇˇˇ
2012-08-22 11:19:49.271 BufferedSamples[637:3b03] /DummyRecorder.m:50: AudioUnitRender result -50 FFFFFFCE Œˇˇˇ
2012-08-22 11:19:49.294 BufferedSamples[637:3b03] /DummyRecorder.m:50: AudioUnitRender result -50 FFFFFFCE Œˇˇˇ
2012-08-22 11:19:49.317 BufferedSamples[637:3b03] /DummyRecorder.m:50: AudioUnitRender result -50 FFFFFFCE Œˇˇˇ
2012-08-22 11:19:49.341 BufferedSamples[637:3b03] /DummyRecorder.m:50: AudioUnitRender result -50 FFFFFFCE Œˇˇˇ
2012-08-22 11:19:49.364 BufferedSamples[637:3b03] /DummyRecorder.m:50: AudioUnitRender result -50 FFFFFFCE Œˇˇˇ
...
```

Comment: Are you checking the result code returned by AudioUnitRender? I recommend doing so with pretty much every Core Audio function call, because unexpected things can go wrong that you won't be informed about otherwise.

I recommend putting something like [this](http://pastebin.com/zMc3xBMS) at the top of your source file, and using checkResult(operation, "action description") everywhere

Comment: Hi Michael, thank you so much for your help! I used your `checkResult` method and i get this: `AudioUnitRender result -50 FFFFFFCE Œˇˇˇ` what does that tell me?

Comment: have a look at your preferred sample rate. I think they are different from sim, to device. Or one or the other is ignored when you set it. That would account for the different buffer behaviour.

Comment: @MaxMacLeod thanks for the suggestion. I tried 44100, 48000 and 96000 without success.

Comment: Ahh, -50 - Apple's least helpful error message =)

There's usually a bit of guess work involved in figuring this stuff out, as it's hard to keep all the parameters in mind, but the first thing I would be trying is setting the stream format on the output scope of your audio unit's input bus (bus 1). Currently you're only setting it on the input scope of the output bus (bus 0), and I'm not 100% certain that that's sufficient.

Comment: @MichaelTyson this did the trick! I am deeply thankful for your help. If you make your comment into an actual answer i will mark it as accepted. I hear you are travelling europe in your motorhome so if you stop by in Germany near Erfurt or Jena, let me know and i'll spend you a tasty beer! No, a whole crate! ;-) Cheers and thanks again, you absolutely made my day!

Comment: Lovely - I'm glad to hear it! Will do.

Oh, no way! My business partner, Sebastian, lives in Erfurt. We'll definitely be heading that way at some point =)

Glad to help! Best of luck.

Comment: Great! I read your blog post about how you spent the last few years in your motorhome, it was very inspiring. I'm serious, drop me a note when you're around and i'll make good on my promise ;) Best of luck to you, too!

Comment: Did you ever get that beer Michael? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's usually a bit of guess work involved in figuring this stuff out, as it's hard to keep all the parameters in mind, but the first thing I would be trying is setting the stream format on the output scope of your audio unit's input bus (bus 1).

Currently you're only setting it on the input scope of the output bus (bus 0), and I'm not 100% certain that that's sufficient.